# How to Change position of elements in python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a python list like

```
the_list= ['john',"nick","edward","mood","enp","wick"]
```

i always want the mood and enp to be in the 0th and 1st index of list rest order can be anything.
so the output will be

```
op_list= ["mood","enp",........rest..]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
op_list = ["mood", "enp"] + [x for x in the_list if x not in ("mood", "enp")]
```

This assumes the two special elements are always present.

Comment: what if i want to specify indexes. like 0,1,2 3